# close child window which is not open using window.open

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to close the child window when user logs out from main window.

I stored URL of the child window from java script to session object using web services. Keep in mind that child window is not opening by `window.open` method.

In aspx page I have a java script code like this:

```
function closepage(sessionvar) {
    window.opener.location = sessionvar;
    window.close();
};
```

Now on aspx code behind page I used this code when user logs out using main window.

```
string sessionvar = Session["CloseURl"].ToString();
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "sessionvar", "closepage()");
```

As usual, it's not working.

I would really appreicate if someone can shed some light on this.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I noticed was that you are not passing the sessionvar to the closepage function in your script injection:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "sessionvar", "closepage()");
```

should be

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "sessionvar", string.Format("closepage('{0}');", sessionvar));
```